# How does MPI_GATHERV work for arrays of dissimilar sizes?

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I am trying to combine arrays from different processors into one single array at the root node. Since the arrays in these different processors are different in size, I call MPI_GATHER first to collect the local array sizes from individual processes at the root. Then I feed the array containing the local sizes into the MPI_GATHERV command at the root. However, on inspection of the output, I found that the combined array is different from individual arrays with entries in the former from the individual arrays jumbled up and sometimes even with different entries.

I have set the padding length to zero. This might be wrong. Pardon my ignorance, I am new to MPI and also because I found the documentation on GATHERV inadequate.

The pseudo code is as following:

```
  call MPI_Gather(Ilocalcnt, 1, MPI_INT, Icntarr,
 & 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err) ! trying to create an array,Icntarr, in the root process containing the size of arrays in each processor. Ilocalcnt is the size of the array Floc. 



  IF(rank.ne.0) THEN
  call MPI_Gatherv(Floc,Ilocalcnt, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, NULL,
 & NULL, NULL,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION ,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err) ! Floc is the local array. Trying to combine everything into F through the next command
  ELSE
  print*, "Icntarr ",Icntarr
  call MPI_Gatherv(Floc,Ilocalcnt, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, F,
 & Icntarr,0, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err) ! F is the combined array
  ENDIF
```

Update- I created a different program capturing only the essentials related to the error. This time the program throws up segmentation errors probably due to the faulty writing of gatherv statement. However, I am at a loss as to how the combining of arrays works under this functionality. To my knowledge, it involves just stating the sizes of individual arrays (let's say 100, 150,250) and collecting them at the root process into one array (of length 500 here) by mentioning the array of sizes, (100,150,250), in the gatherv statement there. The minimal example is presented below.

```
  IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
  include 'mpif.h' ! librerias MPI


   ! MPI
   integer err
   integer flagsolver

   integer rank, size, ierr

   integer stat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
   CHARACTER FILE1*10
   integer,allocatable :: Icntarr(:),Idisarray(:)

   DIMENSION f(200000)
   DIMENSION Floc(200000)


   call MPI_INIT(ierr)
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
   call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
   allocate(Icntarr(size))
   allocate(Idisarray(size))

   Itotal=485
   Iperproc=Itotal/size
   Iend=(rank+1)*Iperproc
   Ibegin=1+(rank)*Iperproc


   IF(rank.eq.size-1) THEN
     Ilocalcnt=Itotal-Ibegin+1
   ELSE
     Ilocalcnt=Iend-Ibegin+1
   ENDIF


   DO I=1,Ilocalcnt
      Floc(I)=rank*0.001
   ENDDO


   print*, "Ilocalcnt ", Ilocalcnt,rank
 

   call MPI_Gather(Ilocalcnt, 1, MPI_INTEGER, Icntarr,
 & 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err)





   IF(rank.ne.0) THEN
   call MPI_Gatherv(Floc,Ilocalcnt, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, NULL,
 & NULL, NULL,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION ,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err)
   ELSE
   print*, "Icntarr ",Icntarr
   Istartdis=0
   DO Idisp=1,size
      Idisarray(Idisp)=Istartdis
      Istartdis=Istartdis+Icntarr(Idisp)
   ENDDO
   call MPI_Gatherv(Floc,Ilocalcnt, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, F,
 & Icntarr,Idisarray, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err)
   ENDIF

   write(FILE1,'(A4,I2,A4)') 'Floc',rank,'.dat'
   open(unit=1401, file=FILE1)


   DO Iloc=1,Ilocalcnt
      write(1401,*) Floc(Iloc)
   ENDDO
   close(1401)

   IF(rank.eq.0) then
   open(unit=1401, file='Fcomb.dat')
   DO I=1,Itotal
   write(1401,*) F(I)
   ENDDO
   ENDIF
   deallocate(Icntarr)
   deallocate(Idisarray)
   call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr) ! finaliza MPI
   END
```

Update2- It works now. I created a displacement array, setting the strides to zero. That way, I got a combined array of length equal to the sum of all individual array lengths.

Comment: you need to create the `displacements` array and pass it to `MPI_Gatherv()`

Comment: What padding are you setting to zero? Please make a [mcve]. Gatherv can be demonstrated on a very short program.

Comment: Note MPI_INT is not part of the Fortran binding for MPI - you want MPI_INTEGER. But as Vladimir says you really ought to supply a short but complete example program this is very difficult

Comment: I'm surprised this code doesn't bomb. Passing a literal zero where there should be a displacements array would normally cause a crash.

Comment: I have modified the post. Please take a look at the updated one.

Comment: First step - help yourself and use `Implicit None`, no new code should use anything else . Second step, use `use mpi`, no new code should use the include file. Basically I've given up trying to help people who won't help themselves by preforming these basic steps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Ian. However, the problem is that I am building on somebody else's code, so I have kept the basic format unchanged. The code was running fine. It started giving errors when I brought in "MPI_GATHERV".